# Changing difficulty levels, pre mining etc of Monero Fork

Tags: monerod, mining, monero-forks, genesisblock

If I have a custom coin based on a Monero Fork and want to change the setup e.g. difficulty levels, pre mined coins etc. As long as I keep the Genesis block the same, are there any implications?